# RcvBufErrors and InErrors peak at about 700/events per second

Tags: networking, server

Netdata Alert:  `1m ipv4 udp receive buffer errors | 23650 errors`

I have a cluster of three servers that are all part of an ELK (Elasticsearch Logstash Kibana) cluster receiving netflow/sflow/ipfix data.  Each server has nginx load balancing a ton of UDP data among the three servers.

**Example:**
A router will send netflow to any one of the servers on UDP port 9995 and will distribute it (with nginx stream) among all of the three servers on udp/2055.  It might forward that packet to the same machine but on port 2055 or it might send it to another machine on port 2055.  Logstash's netflow input is configured to listen on UDP port 2055 only on each machine.  sFlow works the same but it is using udp/9995 distributing to udp/6343 and so on.

This all works fine and without using [netdata](https://github.com/firehol/netdata) one would assume it was working perfectly but I'm seeing the following issue:

Netdata Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNuW8.png

I've been researching this for the most of my time over the last few days now and I am not making any progress whatsoever.  I've tried tuning things with `sysctl` with absolutely no effect.  The same graph pattern continues relentlessly and the RcvBufErrors and InErrors peak at about 700/events per second.  Occasionally I'll see a spike or a dip while making changes in controlled manner but the same pattern always prevails with the same peak values.

The values I've tried increasing with `sysctl` and their current values are:

```
net.core.rmem_default = 8388608
net.core.rmem_max = 33554432
net.core.wmem_default = 52428800
net.core.wmem_max = 134217728
net.ipv4.udp_early_demux = 0 (was 1)
net.ipv4.udp_mem = 764304   1019072 1528608
net.ipv4.udp_rmem_min = 18192
net.ipv4.udp_wmem_min = 8192
net.core.netdev_budget = 10000
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 2000
```

Note I'm also getting the `10min netdev budget ran outs | 5929 events` issue as well but this is less of a concern.  That's why I've increased `net.core.netdev_budget` and `net.core.netdev_max_backlog` described above.

I've also tried raising the number of workers (from 4 to 8), queue size (from 2048 to 4096) and receive buffer (from 32MB to 64MB) for each of the logstash inputs but I'm not seeing any difference either.  I've given plenty of time for the logstash restart and things to reflect the new settings but the issue remains the same.

Any ideas on what I can do to find out what I need to change and how to actually determine what they should be set to would be appreciated.

*Thanks for reading.*